# Fixed ffmpeg with active_record_store rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg

i have a rails application and change to cookie_store to active_record_store, but when i used a converter video in ffmpeg i getting this error

Maybe someone can help me to solve it?

```
error while running command ffmpeg -i "/tmp/9ce6ffe844cfb53c6adb76fef1f3330020160930-13071-hutiuw.mp4" -acodec aac -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -s 720x405 -y "/tmp/9ce6ffe844cfb53c6adb76fef1f3330020160930-13071-hutiuw20160930-13071-1xp6lwi.mp4": Command 'PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; ffmpeg -i "/tmp/9ce6ffe844cfb53c6adb76fef1f3330020160930-13071-hutiuw.mp4" -acodec aac -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -s 720x405 -y "/tmp/9ce6ffe844cfb53c6adb76fef1f3330020160930-13071-hutiuw20160930-13071-1xp6lwi.mp4"' returned 1. Expected 0 Here is the command output: STDOUT: STDERR: ffmpeg version 2.8.6-1ubuntu2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-11ubuntu1) 20160311 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --disable-i686 libavutil 54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100 libavcodec 56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100 libavformat 56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101 libavdevice 56. 4.100 / 56. 4.100 libavfilter 5. 40.101 / 5. 40.101 libavresample 2. 1. 0 / 2. 1. 0 libswscale 3. 1.101 / 3. 1.101 libswresample 1. 2.101 / 1. 2.101 libpostproc 53. 3.100 / 53. 3.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/9ce6ffe844cfb53c6adb76fef1f3330020160930-13071-hutiuw.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : mp42 minor_version : 0 compatible_brands: isommp42 creation_time : 2016-07-12 16:30:41 Duration: 00:04:38.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1520 kb/s Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1325 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default) Metadata: handler_name : VideoHandler Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default) Metadata: creation_time : 2016-07-12 16:30:42 handler_name : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011 [libx264 @ 0xa1105e0] height not divisible by 2 (720x405) Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/9ce6ffe844cfb53c6adb76fef1f3330020160930-13071-hutiuw20160930-13071-1xp6lwi.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : mp42 minor_version : 0 compatible_brands: isommp42 Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 29.97 fps (default) Metadata: handler_name : VideoHandler encoder : Lavc56.60.100 libx264 Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default) Metadata: creation_time : 2016-07-12 16:30:42 handler_name : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011 encoder : Lavc56.60.100 aac Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264)) Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native)) Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: What are you trying to do..uploading a video file or running ffmpeg commands on console....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your choice of cookie store had anything to do with that. This happened because you chose a video file with this particular input size (1280x720).
Error is:

```
[libx264 @ 0xa1105e0] height not divisible by 2 (720x405)
```

There are plenty questions on this site about this error but in the end it boils down to a simple answer: "make sure encoded picture has even width and height". In your case output picture size (720x405) is passed down from your site code so you need to fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the new height/width, you used -1 to let it scale the size, but it chose an odd number, and then complained about it being odd. Clearly a small bug, but easily fixed by replacing -1 with an even number.